# Doesn't a restriction introduced while finding the general solution to a differential equation impact its interval of validity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I've been working on this example in Boyce's Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems book. The example shows how to find a solution to $$y''+4y=3\csc(t)$$ through the method of variation of parameters.

We know that the general solution of the homogeneous equation corresponding to the equation above, $y''+4y=0$, is $y_c(t)=c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)$. So the idea of the method is to replace $c_1$ and $c_2$ with the functions $u_1$ and $u_2$, respectively, and then try to determine these functions so that the expression $y=u_1\cos(2t)+u_2\sin(2t)$ is a solution to the non-homogeneous equation. At this point we would calculate the first and second derivatives of this last expression and substitute for $y$ in the non-homogeneous equation, what would lead us to one equation involving a combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$, and their derivatives. That allows us to impose a second condition so that we obtain two equations for two unknown functions $u_1$ and $u_2$.

In the example, they require that $u'_1\cos(2t)+u'_2\sin(2t)=0$. That condition, after we've done the calculations, leads us to the following system:
$$\begin{cases}
u'_1\cos(2t)+u'_2\sin(2t)=0 \\\\
-2u'_1\sin(2t)+2u'_2\cos(2t)=3\csc(t)
\end{cases}
$$

Now, the example goes on to solve this system beginning with $$u'_2=-u'_1\frac{\cos(2t)}{\sin(2t)}$$
Since we can't divide by zero, we have to suppose also that $\sin(2t)\ne0$, which implies $t\ne n\frac{\pi}{2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. But the book doesn't make this observation. It just moves on to find both $u'_1$ and $u'_2$ and, after integration, declares that $u_1=-3\sin(t)+c_1$ and $u_2=\frac{3}{2}\ln{|\csc(t)-\cot(t)|}+3\cos(t)+c_2$. These two last results, after some more manipulations, give us the general solution to our differential equation: $$y=3\sin(t)+\frac{3}{2}\ln{|\csc(t)-\cot(t)|}\sin(2t)+c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)$$

My question lies in that consideration not made by the book of $\sin(2t)$ not being equal to zero. I think that if we were solving a system of equations problem, not a differential equation one, taking into consideration only the system above, we would have to analyze both the case when $\sin(2t)\ne0$ and the case when $\sin(2t)=0$. Why doesn't the book take this restriction into account? Doesn't that impact at all the interval of validity of the general solution found at the end?

OBS: I'm taking my first course on differential equations, so I may be missing some key information or insight here.

Comment: Its fine if $u_2$ blows up when $\sin(2t)=0$ as long as the their product remains finite.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Let me see if I get what you mean: since $u_2$ has vertical asymptotes when $\sin(2t)=0$, it blows up near these values of $t$. But it would not be a problem as long as the product $u_2\sin(2t)$ remains finite. I used GeoGebra to look at this product and the result of $u_2\sin(2t)$ is actually a function without any vertical asymptotes. That's strange to me! If we are looking at exactly the point, let's say, $t=\pi$, isn't $u_2$ actually undefined there?

Comment: $1/t$ isn't defined at $t=0$, but $(1/t)\sin t$ can be defined to be $1$ at $t=0$. You're doing differential equations, you must have done Calculus & limits, this sort of thing should be second nature to you by now.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I need to brush up on some of those concepts. But now I get the point you guys are saying. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was thinking about what you said. $f(t)=(1/t)\sin t$ has a removable discontinuity at $t=0$. We would have to define $f(0)$ to be equal to $1$ in order to get rid of the discontinuity. But without that definition, $f(t)$ would continue to have that discontinuity. So, in the case of my question, $u_2\sin(2t)$, as well as the general solution to the problem, would, in fact, have removable discontinuities at points such as $t=\pi$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.